# SQL order by one data on the top in xcode

Tags: sql, xcode, sql-order-by

how can I arrange my data into ascending format but put one of the data one top

```
Column 
_______
g
c
e
b
d
Home
a
f
```

what I want to happen is

```
Column 
_______
Home
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

What I'm using now is

```
SELECT * FROM  table ORDER BY `column` ASC
```

Comment: Try something like `ORDER BY CASE WHEN column = 'Home' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, `column` ASC`.

Comment: Is it a fixed string you want first all the time (in which case user2989408's comment looks good) or is there another criteria for selection like length?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work in order to achieve this.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN column = 'Home' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, column ASC
```